# Parquet row group size for storing similar logs

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have the following requirement to analyze logs created in the following way:

- Thousands of nodes record logs
- Logs are created at same time by the nodes
- Logs at a given time are very similar to one another
- Size of each log at a given time is a few kilobytes, but together (ie, over all times) for any node, they run into several gigabytes
- Analysis should be done over logs at a given time
- Spark framework is tentatively chosen for analysis

Prima facie, given very high commonality ,delta encoding would be helpful to efficiently store and Parquet seems to be a natural choice. However, it would be helpful to know how block-size would  affect storage. I intend the pre-process the data, store in Parquet and do analysis on it multiple times later.

1. If I chose 128MB as size of row group, would it result in reading 128MB of data splitting across columns within a single row, (OR)
2. Maximum rows that will fit into 128MB (both within row group of course)?

Would I be correct to assume that performance will be different both cases?